# Spark Dataframe .show() output not aligned

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark

I have local Spark installed. Running in VSCode on Jupyter Notebook.

Using this test code to create small dataframe and show it in the console using .show(), but my output is not aligned:

```
# %%
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-application-name").getOrCreate()
)
sc = spark.sparkContext

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled",True)

import pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkByExamples.com").getOrCreate()


columns = ["language", "users_count"]

data = [
    ("Java", "20000"),
    ("Python", "100000"),
    ("Scala", "3000"),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

df.cache()

df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

Also converting to pandas and printing shows similarly:

```
df_pd = df.toPandas()
print(df_pd)
```

[image]

Can you help me, where can I look to try to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "output is not aligned"? Can you mention the expected output in the question?

Comment: Like on the picture, you see that pipes are not making vertical column, and on some rows they are pushed to right or left. Well anyway, somehow it got fixed, Not really know how, probably after restarting vscode.